# Passing data to components and accessing data from parent using vue and vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vue-props

Am having this problem with vue 2.6 and vue router 3.
I have set up the router and vue instance like so:

```js
const Settings = {
    props: ['showForm'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            // some data
        }
    },
   template: '#Settings'
}
const Norm = {
    props: ['showForm'],
    data: function () {
        return {
            //some data
        }
   },
  template: '#test'
}
const routes =[
    {path: '/',component:  Norm},
    {path:'/settings', component: Settings}
]
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes 
})
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data: function () {
       return {
          //some data
           isConfigured: false,
        },
    },
   created: function (){
      //some codes called 
   },
   components: {
    'Settings': Settings,
    'Norm': Norm  
},
router: router
})
```

And the index.html file looks like this:

```html
<div id='app'>
  <div class="nav-bar">
     <ul>
        <li><router-link to="/">Home</router-link ></li>
         <li><router-link to="/Settings ">Settings</router-link></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <router-view></router-view>
  <script type="text/x-template" id="settings">
    <section :showForm="isConfigured">
       {{ showForm +',' +isConfigured}}
     </section>
  <script type="text/x-template" id="test">
    <section :showForm="isConfigured">
       {{showForm +',' +isConfigured}}
    </section>
  </script>
</div>
<script src="vue-router.js">
<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

It seems the data is not passed to the showForm prop because it renders as:

```
Undefined, false
```

And it seems the Norm prop receives no data neither can it access data in the vue instance because it renders:

```
Undefined, Undefined
```

.

Vue responds with the following error

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "showForm" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "isConfigured" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I believe the second error above is for the norm component. While the first error is logged twice for both components. Please what am I doing wrong.

Comment: You need to show the `section component` script.  Do you expose the showForm property in the `props` section?

Comment: Yes, there are no other components script, everything is defined there

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your x-templates outside of the application template.

Also, the `section` element does not have a `showForm` property.  You need to send your props into the components using the router.  You will have to use a common source of truth for your `isConfigured` property to use it in both the app component and the router components.

So for an `showForm` property:

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="test">
  <section v-show="showForm">
    I am configured
  </section>
</script>
```

You would pass props in like this:

```js
const routes =[
    {path: '/',component:  Norm, props: {showForm: isConfigured},
    {path:'/settings', component: Settings, props: {showForm: isConfigured} }
]
```

Finally, you do not need to declare your routes as child components of the app.

Comment: I've tried that,that shouldn't be the issue since it is rendered as "undefined,undefined".

Comment: I would cause the template to not have an options object assigned to it, resulting in the error.

Comment: in the script am using, its actually ```template: '#test'```

Comment: Try to move your x-templates outside of the application template.

Comment: It's worse now both components are rendering "undefined, undefined"

Comment: That's better really :).  Now lets try the rest of my solution.

Comment: this new solution throws an error.  >isConfigured is not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239440/discussion-between-peter-orji-and-steven-spungin).

Comment: Yes you need to define it outside.  In your app you hard-coded it, so just hard code it for now.  That is what i mean by "common source of truth".  You probably do not need it in the app though.  Vuex might be a good solution for that.

Comment: If you instantiate the app, you can also get it from the instance.  `{isConfigured: theApp.isConfigured}`